# How can I pass a variable between 2 U-SQL scripts

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to filter values in a table using values in another table. Since USQL doesn't allow to use another table with the WHERE IN statement, my thoughts were to use a usql function to create a list of values and then pass that along to my main script.

Any ideas as to how I can pass the necessary variable? I would also be interested if there are other ways of aproaching this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to filter your dataset with SEMIJOIN OR ANTISEMIJOIN in USQL. Its the  usql way dealing with IN/NOT IN

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/semijoin)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I clarified the question, since it was a slip on my side. I don't want to drop the entire row, just that specific value. since I am new to USQL it seemed that IN would do the job but it cannot achieve what I want. Added an answer with the solution that ended up working for me.

Comment: Hi Cristian. Nice that you find a solution that works. I would suggest you also to look at user-defined operators if you are familiar with c#. 
They are powerful tools for some complex join logic, etc. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide#use-user-defined-objects-udo

Comment: I am begining to become more familiar with c# as it has been the solution to many of my issues wthin the current project.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing 2 c# functions as code behind to achieve what I want within a single script. The first function actually checks the input table for the values I need and creates a list. I use this function to declare a variable at the begining of my usql script. I then us this list as input to a second function that processes the values in my work table.

This is my current solution and it is working very well. I'm still new to U-SQL so if there is an easier way of doing this I would like to learn about it, so feel free to still contribute to this thread.